# How create an apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

I gave my daughter my old iPhone but I forgot all the information about the apple ID. I want to create a new one and disable the other one, or just delete the entire ID. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1) Call Apple Customer service and they will be able to help you. That's the hard way.

2) You can also delete your iCloud account if you don't have any purchases of content attached to it. I highly doubt that you don't need the account and that's why I would tell your daughter to go to the iPhone Settings>>iCloud>>Sign Out. She can then sign in with her own iCloud/Apple ID. If she doesn't have one, she can set up a new [Apple ID and new iCloud account by following these steps](http://www.idropnews.com/2016/08/04/how-to-create-an-apple-id-and-set-up-an-icloud-account-on-iphone-ipad-and-mac/). While at it, she'll make things a lot easier if her icloud account is the same as her apple ID account. Access to all of your content will be much more simple. This is a mistake a lot of people make. I highly recommend you have only one account/pass for both.

In case you still want to delete your iCloud account and deactivate it, here is how to:
[How to delete your iCloud account](http://www.idropnews.com/2016/08/26/how-to-deactivate-your-icloud-account/)

I hope all this helps :)

Comment: TBH, the support service is pretty Awesome, I don't know if thats just my experience, but if you have an issue thats kinda hard or something they are really helpful, plus they will normally just do it all for you, thats the reason Apples are rather pricy - their support is Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [Apple My Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com) website.

There you will find a link to [Find your Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid?returnURL=https://appleid.apple.com&app_id=93&language=US-EN), try this as first step. If you can't find or restore you Apple Id, you can Create a new one in the same site.